# Fade in effect on info box triggers too often

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

When asking a question or editing an existing one, the fade-in on the "How to Tag" / "How to Format" box

`<div class="module newuser" id="how-to-title"></div>`

fires whenever the focus is changed between the title box, question body text box and the tags textbox.  While it's not a functionality issue, it does get somewhat annoying watching that thing blink in and out.

Comment: Now that it blinks, you pay more attention to it, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We believe these boxes, which contain important FAQ style info, were being ignored by most users.

So the fade-in is intentional.

(Note that on edit, there's less fading when editing an answer.)

How often are you tabbing amongst these fields?

Comment: I personally am tabbing fairly often.  I tab down to Save out of the body field when editing because I'm a keyboard guy so it fires pretty often for me.  I don't know, I equate it with <blink></blink>.  Still pretty annoying.  I think that the box following you during scrolling is sufficient.